# Download .txt from URL string in R

Tags: r, url, web-scraping, finance, edgar

I am working with the EDGAR package in R to download Apple's 2005 Annual Report. This is my code to get that far:

```
library(edgar)

getMasterIndex(2005)

aapl<-getFilings(2005,320193, '10-K')
```

This was my output when I did that:

```
> aapl<-getFilings(2005,320193, '10-K')
Total number of filings to be downloaded=1. Do you want to download  (yes/no)? yes

> aapl
                                           Link      Status
1        https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/0001104659-05-058421.txt 
   Download success
```

To me this looks like I just retrieved the URL to this particular document, I did not actually download the text file.

My next step I imagine would be to download the file based on URL. I thought doing a download.file using AAPL as my URL argument would work but I must be missing something.

Thoughts on how to download the full doc based on the URL? Thank you

Comment: From documentation: `Function creates new directory 'Edgar filings' to store all downloaded filings`.

Comment: Thank you! I did find a folder in My Documents with that name and my file.